# CSS display:inline-block changes text size on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have set up a very simple webpage which works the way I intend on a desktop browser, but shows strange results on mobile. Here is the code :

```css
body {
  font-family: "Raleway", "Tahoma", "Helvetica", "Arial", Sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.4;
  color: #303030;
  font-size: 20px;
}

a,
a:visited {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

#container {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 30px auto 0px auto;
}

#links .name {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
  width: 90px;
}

#links .link {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.box {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  padding: 20px 20px;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #D0D0D0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <section class="box">
        Hi ! My name is <strong>Name</strong>. You might also know me as <strong>User</strong>. Bla bla bla, this is some text here. But not too much.
      </section>
      <section class="box">
        My main interests are <strong>hobby 1</strong>, <strong>hobby 2</strong>.
      </section>
      <section class="box">
        Reach me easily on <a href="https://twitter.com/Protectator">Twitter</a> !
        <br>
        <br> You can also find me on
        <ul id="links">
          <li>
            <div class="name">Twitter</div>
            <div class="link"><a href="https://twitter.com/Protectator">@Username</a></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="name">Facebook</div>
            <div class="link"><a href="https://www.facebook.com">Username</a></div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div class="name">Google+</div>
            <div class="link"><a href="https://plus.google.com">+Username</a></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly and displays things the way I want when viewed in a dekstop browser :
[image]

However, when I view the page from a mobile device, the size of the text of `<li>` elements get reduced compared to the rest of the page. Here is how it looks :

[image]

I have no idea why this happens. Looking at it through the dev tools, it seems like the `font-size` of the first two `<section>` elements goes up when on mobile (I've set it to `20px` in `body`, but they go way higher in reality :
[image]).

The thing I don't understand is then why doesn't this **also** happen on the `<li>` elements ? I could use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but then the page would look ugly on phone, which is not what I'm looking for. I just want the text to be the same size on the page.

It seems like the `display: inline-block` is what causes this, but can't find an other way to achieve aligning the `<a>` elements vertically only using `inline` elements.

Comment: Maybe a _viewport_ issue. Try adding to the `<head>` part: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: @Django Thanks, but I just tried and it makes no difference.

Comment: Is that an emulator you are testing on?

Comment: @MisterEpic I'm using Chrome's dev tools to simulate the resolution of an iPhone, and I also use a physical Android phone. I get the same result on both.

Comment: Hmm... Shot in the dark, but try changing the line-height on the body, it needs a unit: 1.4em

Comment: @MisterEpic Thanks, but that didn't work.

Comment: Just to make sure, your real code does have a `<head>` element?

Comment: @connexo Yes ;) Just thought it wouldn't be useful to put it here. And I don't import any other css than what I showed here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Solution:

Just turn

```
#container {
  width: 900px;
}
```

into

```
#container {
  max-width: 900px;
}
```

and also apply

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

in the `<head`>-section of your html. Check [here](http://www.codestylers.de/so/39550403/index.html), I've set it up on my own server (to stay there) for your reference. Find the [css here](http://www.codestylers.de/so/39550403/styles.css).

### What happens here:

Since your `#container` did have a **fixed** `width: 900px` your mobile browser *automatically scales it down to fit the viewport width*. Since browsers do this in an intelligent way, they do increase the font-size of elements to match the intended font-size of elements (which is why you saw much bigger font-size in calculated styles than in the stylesheet).

For some strange reason I cannot explain the browser does not seem to do this for all elements, though.

[image: iPhone 6+ portrait view of website]

Comment: Thank you for the solution and the explanation. Still strange that the browser seem to ignore some elements with that scaling.

Answer (score 1):

I faced very similar issue while developing a responsive app whose font should look same in tablet browser and desktop browser (Chrome here)

So, what fixed for me is using `flex` or `inline-block` for display

```
#container {
  display: flex; \* or display:inline-block *\
}
```

I am not sure why it works but this works great